# Twitter API Truncating Tweet by Adding URL

Tags: twitter, tweepy, tweets, truncated

I'm trying to get tweets from twitter using tweepy but I keep getting truncated tweets. I understand that twitter automatically truncates tweets if the RT is added to the front making it too long so in that case you would use the retweeted_status element to get the original text. My problem is that the retweeted_status is being truncated by twitter because it seems to add a URL to the end.

text:  RT @nytgraphics: President Trump is at his VA golf course today. It’s his 16th visit to the club as president.…

retweeted_status:  President Trump is at his VA golf course today. It’s his 16th visit to the club as president.…https://twitter.com/i/web/status/917430220499685376
(there is actually a shortened twitter link here but SO wont let me put a shortened link)

I'm not sure why it does this. The retweeted status is marked as truncated but not as retweeted or quoted.

How can I just get the original text of the retweet or just get the full text of everything (AKA RT @soandso "untruncated text")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can get extended tweets. It is documented [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/tweet-updates).

Supply this parameter to your request: `tweet_mode=extended`. 
Get the extended tweet text in this field: `full_text`.

Comment: I thought this worked as I looked into the documentation and found what I needed to make the extended tweets work for my stream, but I am still getting tweets truncated even when 'truncated' is not set to true. I have to use the normal 'text' sometimes because the stream is still in compatibility mode and not every tweet contains 'full_text'. So I can only use the extended tweet when it exists, and when it doesn't twitter still seems to be truncating the tweet.

Comment: Also the tweets that are cut off are not necessary 140 characters.

Comment: Are the tweets that are cutoff and that do not have `truncated=true` retweets?

Comment: Yes they were. I seemed to have fixed the issue however. I had assumed that if the tweet was truncated due to a retweet that it would be marked as truncated, but that doesn't seem to be the case. So I checked for the re-tweeted status dictionary and then dealt with it that way. Thank you for your help!